# No module named urllib3.exceptions

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, urllib3

New to programming here. I was trying to follow a programming project i found online.

(For those that are curious, the link is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkVBAcvbrjU)

I tried to run python smartmirror.py

However, when I run that command, i get this thrown back at me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smartmirror.py", line 9, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/pi/Smart-Mirror/requests/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ImportError: No module named urllib3.exceptions
```

I ran `pip3 freeze` to see if I had urllib3 installed. Turns out that I had `urllib3==1.25.7` installed. I even ran `pip3 install --upgrade six` to ensure that I had the latest version.

However, afte this. I ran 'python smartmirror.py' and still encountered:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "smartmirror.py", line 9, in <module>
        import requests
      File "/home/pi/Smart-Mirror/requests/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
        from .packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
    ImportError: No module named urllib3.exceptions
```

**System**
Raspberry Pi 3

Any help with this would be extremely great. So sorry if I have not asked a well documented question.

Thanks!

Comment: [Edit] your question and show the output of: `pip3 show requests` and inside `smartmirror.py` the outuput of: `import sys ; print(sys.version)`

Comment: It looks like `pip3` and `python` don't refer to the same Python installation. Can you try running `python3 -m pip install ---upgrade requests urllib3` and then `python3 smartmirror.py`?

Comment: @QuentinPradet . Hi, I will amend it as such. Thanks for the help, I will update this page as soon as I get the chance to. 

Thanks so much!

Comment: @stovfl 

Hi there, new to stack overflow and programming as a whole.

In what sense should I change my question? What can I do to make it a better one? 

Also, what do you mean by show the inside of smartmirror.py?

Comment: @Matthew They wanted you to run `pip3 show requests` in your terminal and add the output of that command to your question. They also wanted you to add `import sys ; print(sys.version)` in your `smartmirror.py` file and then run it again with `python smartmirror.py` and show us the output of the command. You have an installation issue, so we're trying to figure it out. Oh, and did you install `requests` with pip? You should not have to fetch the resource by yourself.

Comment: @QuentinPradet, thanks for the speedy reply.

I ran pip3 show requests and these are the output:
 
Name: requests
Version: 2.22.0
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: http://python-requests.org
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: idna, chardet, certifi, urllib3

Per the second point, I have some new lines of code to write. Allow me to do that first. Thanks!